# jQuery mobile slider change event not triggering

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I'm loading some html through an ajax-call.

This html also contains javascript in `<script>` tags.

These script tags runs but I try to attach an event handler to the change-event of an `<input slider>` (part of the JQM library).

This works if I use the 'deprecated' `.live()`. Problem is this html is loaded several times and each the event handler is re added every time.

If I instead use `.on()` as DOCS suggests the event is not triggered when I change the value of the input.

```
"input type="range" name="betInput" id="Size-@sel.UniqueId" min="0" max="@sel.AvailableToBet"/"

// Using .live() here works but keeps adding
$('#Size-@sel.UniqueId').on('change', function () {

                    console.debug('Should print when slider-value is changed but is not');
                });


                // This next line will however trigger the event above.
                $('#Size-@sel.UniqueId').trigger('change');
```

USING JQuery 1.8.2 and JQM 1.2.0

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a selector to make the `on` act like `live`:

```
// Using .live() here works but keeps adding
$('#Size-@sel.UniqueId').on('change', function () {
```

Should be something like:

```
$('parentSelector').on('change', ,'#Size-@sel.UniqueId', function () {
```

Read more in the [docs](http://api.jquery.com/on/):

> If selector is omitted or is null, the event handler is referred to as
>   direct or directly-bound. The handler is called every time an event
>   occurs on the selected elements, whether it occurs directly on the
>   element or bubbles from a descendant (inner) element.
>
> When a selector is provided, the event handler is referred to as
>   delegated. The handler is not called when the event occurs directly on
>   the bound element, but only for descendants (inner elements) that
>   match the selector. jQuery bubbles the event from the event target up
>   to the element where the handler is attached (i.e., innermost to
>   outermost element) and runs the handler for any elements along that
>   path matching the selector.
>
> Event handlers are bound only to the currently selected elements; they
>   must exist on the page at the time your code makes the call to .on().
>   To ensure the elements are present and can be selected, perform event
>   binding inside a document ready handler for elements that are in the
>   HTML markup on the page. If new HTML is being injected into the page,
>   select the elements and attach event handlers after the new HTML is
>   placed into the page. Or, use delegated events to attach an event
>   handler, as described next.
>
> Delegated events have the advantage that they can process events from
>   descendant elements that are added to the document at a later time. By
>   picking an element that is guaranteed to be present at the time the
>   delegated event handler is attached, you can use delegated events to
>   avoid the need to frequently attach and remove event handlers. This
>   element could be the container element of a view in a
>   Model-View-Controller design, for example, or document if the event
>   handler wants to monitor all bubbling events in the document. The
>   document element is available in the head of the document before
>   loading any other HTML, so it is safe to attach events there without
>   waiting for the document to be ready.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your event from 'change' to 'slidestop' like this:

```
$('#Size-@sel.UniqueId').on('slidestop', function () {
```

This answer helped me out: [jQueryMobile slider change event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16799382/jquerymobile-slider-change-event)