# jQuerymobile slider touch lags

Tags: jquery-mobile, charts, slider, flot

I'm using a slider to change the min/max for chart I'm displaying with flot.

This is my slider HTML:

```
<div id=timerangeslider>
        <form>
            <div class="ui-grid-a" id="slider3">
            <label for="slider-2">Anzeige-Zeitraum (in Stunden):</label>
            <input type="range" name="slider-2" id="slider-2" data-highlight="true" min="1" max="48" value="24">
            </div><!-- /ui-grid -->
        </form></div>
```

And this is my jQuery:

```
function timerangeslider() {
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#slider-2").change("click",function() {
            timerange = $("#slider-2").val();
            energyPlot(d,timerange)
        });
    });
}
```

The function gets called on "pageinit".
It calls another function "energyPlot" which updates my chart (using flot)

Problem with this solution is, that is re-draws my chart on every change of the value of "#slider-2"
So this works, but looks like crap.

Another solution would be this:

```
function timerangeslider() {
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(document).on("click","#timerangeslider",function(event) {
            timerange = $("#slider-2").val();
            energyPlot(d,timerange)
        });
    });
}
```

Problem here is, that on my device (with Phonegap) it does not recognize touches on the actual slider. You can click the number left to the slider and it get's the touch, but not if you drag the slider.
It works in browser though.

Any ideas how to react to touches on the actual slider (on device with phonegap)
Or any ideas for the first solution on how to re-draw the chart only when the slider stopped?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just found the solution here [jQueryMobile slider change event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16799382/jquerymobile-slider-change-event?rq=1)

It seems there is an event for a slider called "slidestop" and you can listen for it.

So I used this:

```
function timerangeslider() {
        $("#slider-2").on("slidestop",function(event) {
            timerange = $("#slider-2").val();
            energyPlot(d,timerange);
        });
}
```